# Is type inference done by an interpreter static or dynamic?

Tags: typing

Type inference can be done by a compiler, and in such cases, type inference is static.

Type inference can also be done by an interpreter. An interpreter does the jobs of both compilation and execution. So is type inference done by an interpreter static or dynamic?

This question is an example that motivated my question [Does "static" or "dynamic" imply a compiler or interpreter implementation of a programming language?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/63544/does-static-or-dynamic-imply-a-compiler-or-interpreter-implementation-of-a-p) at a more general level.

Comment: I think it depends on the semantics of the language, not the implementation. There are interpreters for statically typed languages, and compilers for dynamic languages.

Comment: Thanks. How does  it depend on what aspects of the semantics of the language?

Comment: The terms "static" and "dynamic" are a bit slippery. You might have to define them. It's possible that in doing so, you will find the answer to your own question.

Answer (score 4):

Typically , type inference in interpreted languages happens after parsing (because type inference works on ASTs) but before interpretation (= execution). Both compilers and  interpreters have a phase distinction between type inference, and the execution. The former happens strictly before the latter.

---

BTW, it's wrong to say that an "interpreter does the jobs of both compilation and execution". An interpreter does *not* do compilation.

- A **compiler** is a meta-program that takes as input a program and outputs another program (the executable). It is this output that is executed.
- An **interpreter** is a meta-program that takes as input a program and executes it.

Maybe the following picture clarifies the issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. ' type inference in interpreted languages happens after parsing (because type inference works on ASTs) but before interpretation (= execution).' If I am correct, dynamic means at run time. So do you mean that type inference interpreted languages is typically done statically not dynamically?

Comment: @Tim What I meant is that type inference in statically typed interpreted languages happens before the actual interpretation, after lexing / parsing. The actual interpretation process starts only after type inference, and when the program is actually typable. This is different from interpreting dynamically typed languages.

Comment: by ' The actual interpretation process', do you mean execution? So does at actual interpretation time means the same as at run time?